# how can i use xmlimport function in googlesheet to get different values from DIV with same class name?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

This is the HTML code on the webpage from where I am trying to **scrape** values:

```
<div class="parentclass">
   <div class="subclass">
      <a class="subclass1" href="https://www.google.com">         
         <span class="_getvalclass">This is a sample text</span>
      </a>
   </div>
   <div class="subclass1">
      <div class="_getvalclass">2:30</div>      
   </div>
   <div class="subclass1">
      <div class="_getvalclass">105</div>      
   </div>
   </div>
```

I am using this function in google sheet

```
=SUBSTITUTE(CLEAN(IMPORTXML("http://www.pagename.com", "//div[@class='_getvalclass']")),",","&#44;")
```

I am getting this value:

```
2:30
```

Right now I have two divs with same class name "_getvalclass", is there any way I can target each div and get separate values? like targeting div with index: _getvalclass[0],   _getvalclass[1]

or is there any other way?

Part -2 question (HTML below):

```
<div class="o39aH">
   <div class="_3sle8">
      <a class="T3XY3" href="/some-page">
         <span class="_2KIv8">Test</span>
         <span class="_2UUUp">Unique text only in some page (some page it is missing)</span>
      </a>
   </div>
   <div class="T3XY3">
      <div class="_2KIv8">2:30</div>
      <div class="_2UUUp">Time</div>
   </div>
   <div class="T3XY3">
      <div class="_2KIv8">100</div>
      <div class="_2UUUp">Pounds</div>
   </div>
   <button class="T3XY3">
      <div class="_2KIv8">some text</div>
      <div class="_2UUUp">Favorite</div>
   </button>
   <button class="T3XY3">
      <div class="_2KIv8">Other text</div>
      <div class="_2UUUp">Playlist</div>
   </button>
</div>
```

In some cases, I would like to pull these values

```
<div class="_2KIv8">2:30</div>
<div class="_2UUUp">Time</div>
```

In other cases, I would like to pull these values

```
  <div class="_2KIv8">100</div>
  <div class="_2UUUp">Pounds</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

### Answer for Question 1:

If you want to retrieve `2:30` using the xpath with the index of "div", how about the following xpath?

#### Sample xpath:

```
//div[@class='parentclass']/div[2]
```

or

```
//div[@class='parentclass']/div[2]/div[@class='_getvalclass']/text()
```

#### Sample formula:

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//div[@class='parentclass']/div[2]")
```

- In this case, `http://www.pagename.com` is put in the cell "A1".

#### Note:

- You can test the xpath at [here](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html).
- I'm not sure about your actual URL. So I'm not sure whether above xpath can be directly used for your situation. Because I'm not sure whether the HTML contents in your question can be retrieved by `IMPORTXML`.

If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

### Answer for Question 2:

#### Sample xpath:

Pattern 1:

```
//div[@class='o39aH']/div[2]
```

and

```
//div[@class='T3XY3'][1]
```

and

```
//div[@class='o39aH']/div[@class='T3XY3'][1]
```

Pattern 2:

```
//div[@class='o39aH']/div[3]
```

and

```
//div[@class='T3XY3'][2]
```

and

```
//div[@class='o39aH']/div[@class='T3XY3'][2]
```

#### Sample formulas:

Please put the URL to the cell "A1".

Pattern 1:

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//div[@class='o39aH']/div[2]")
```

- In this case, `2:30` and `Time` are retrieved.

Pattern 2:

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//div[@class='o39aH']/div[3]")
```

- In this case, `100` and `Pounds` are retrieved.

#### Note:

- You can test the xpath at [here](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html).
- If you want to retrieve `Test` and `Unique text only in some page (some page it is missing)`, you can use the xpath of `//div[@class='o39aH']/div[@class='_3sle8']/a[@class='T3XY3']`.

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike for your response. I do have one question. What if I have multiple parentdivs with same class as well. In  that case, how to target specific parent div like 1 or 2 or 3rd parentdiv and then childdiv 1, 2 or 3rd?

Comment: I am trying something like this and it is not working: `=SUBSTITUTE(CLEAN(IMPORTXML(A1, "//div[@class='_parentdivclass']/div[2]/div[@class='_childdivclass']/div[1]")),",","&#44;")`

Comment: @kuml Thank you for replying. 1. At first, can I ask you whether my answer could resolve your this question? 2. About your new question, I would like to support you. But I cannot understand about your situation from your replying and `not working`. This is due to my poor English skill. I have to apologize for this. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, can you provide the sample HTML or URL for understanding your situation?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike i just updated my question and added part-2 with sample html and what I am trying to get. Thank you for your help

Comment: @kuml Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. I added an answer for your 2nd question. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Great as always

Comment: @Shadow Ball Thank you so much.

Comment: @kuml Did my answers show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike thank you so much for help. Your solution works and I like it a lot. I learned something new. I have marked your solution as answer.

Comment: @kuml Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.